# Unity OnCollisionEnter not registering

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, collision-detection

I'm trying to add collision detection to my game, to test it I set it to print "Collision" in the debug but nothing shows up. The two objects physically collide, but the collision doesn't register.

```
public class DamageTrap : MonoBehaviour
{    
    void OnCollisionEnter (Collision col)
    { 
        if (col.gameObject.name == "Player")
        {
            Debug.Log("Collision");
        }
    }
}
```

I have assigned Rigibody2D and 2D colliders to the player and trap. I have double checked and the player is under the tag Player.

Comment: I guess the other thing to ask is if the `DamageTrap` object is connected to the correct object, and if the script is enabled in the editor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You say that you have added a `Rigidbody2D` and 2D colliders to the player and the trap object, yet you are using the `OnCollisionEnter` callback in your script. You should instead be using the `OnCollisionEnter2D` callback if you want 2D physics notifications.

I would suggest marking the trap collider as a trigger and then using the `OnTriggerEnter2D` callback instead as the `OnCollisionEnter2D` is a bit more cumbersome (especially when you are bringing in the `Collision2D` parameter).

So the final code would look like:

```
public class DamageTrap : MonoBehaviour
{    
    void OnTriggerEnter2D (Collider2D col)
    { 
        if (col.gameObject.tag == "Player")
        {
            Debug.Log("Collision");
        }
    }
}
```